# Why doesn't Python have an instancemethod function?

Tags: python

Why doesn't Python have an `instancemethod` function analogous to `staticmethod` and `classmethod`?

Here is how this arose for me. Suppose I have an object which I know will be hashed frequently and whose hash is expensive to calculate. Under this assumption, it is reasonable to compute the hash value once and cache it, as in the following toy example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self._hash_cache = hash(self.x)

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash_cache
```

The `__hash__` function in this class does very little, just an attribute lookup and a return. Naively, it seems it ought to be equivalent to instead write:

```py
class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self._hash_cache = hash(self.x)

    __hash__ = operator.attrgetter('_hash_cache')
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter), `operator.attrgetter` returns a callable object that fetches the given attribute from its operand.  If its operand is `self`, then it will return `self._hash_cache`, which is the desired result. Unfortunately this does not work:

```
>>> hash(A(1))
1
>>> hash(B(1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: attrgetter expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

The reason for this is as follows. If one reads [the descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods), one finds that class dictionaries store methods as functions; functions are non-data descriptors whose `__get__` method returns a bound method.  But `operator.attrgetter` does not return a *function*; it returns a *callable object*.  And in fact, it is a callable object with no `__get__` method:

```
>>> hasattr(operator.attrgetter('_hash_cache'), '__get__')
False
```

Lacking a `__get__` method, this of course will not automatically be turned into a bound method.  We can make a bound method from it using `types.MethodType`, but using it in our class `B` would require creating a bound method for every object instance and assigning it to `__hash__`.

We can see the fact that `operator.attrgetter` has no `__get__` directly if we browse the CPython source. I'm not very familiar with the CPython API, but I believe that what's going on is as follows. The definition of the `attrgetter_type` is in [Modules/_operator.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_operator.c), at line 1439 as I write this. This type sets `tp_descr_get` to `0`. And according to the [type object documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_descr_get), that means an object whose type is `attrgetter_type` will not have a `__get__`.

Of course, if we give ourselves a `__get__` method, then everything works. This is the case in the first example above, where `__hash__` is actually a function and not just a callable. It's also true in some other cases. For example, if we want to lookup a class attribute, we could write the following:

```py
class C:
    y = 'spam'
    get_y = classmethod(operator.attrgetter('y'))
```

As written this is terribly un-Pythonic (though it might be defensible if there were a strange custom `__getattr__` for which we wanted to provide convenience functions).  But at least it gives the desired result:

```
>>> C.get_y()
'spam'
```

I can't think of any reason why it would be bad for `attrgetter_type` to implement `__get__`.  But on the other hand, even if it did, there would be other situations where we run into trouble.  For example, suppose we have a class whose instances are callable:

```py
class D:
    def __call__(self, other):
        ...
```

We can't use an instance of this class as a class attribute and expect instance lookups to generate bound methods.  For instance,

```py
d = D()

class E:
    apply_d = d
```

When `D.__call__` is called, it will receive `self` but not `other`, and that generates a `TypeError`.  This example might be a little far-fetched, but I'd be a little surprised if nobody had ever encountered something like this in practice.  It could be fixed by giving `D` a `__get__` method; but if `D` is from a third-party library that could be inconvenient.

It seems that the easiest solution would be to have an `instancemethod` function.  Then we could write `__hash__ = instancemethod(operator.attrgetter('_hash_cache'))` and `apply_d = instancemethod(d)` and they would both work as intended.  Yet, as far as I know, no such function exists.  Hence my question: Why is there no `instancemethod` function?

---

EDIT: Just to be clear, the functionality of `instancemethod` would be equivalent to:

```py
def instancemethod(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This could be applied as in the original question above.  One could also imagine writing a class decorator that could be applied to `D` that would give it a `__get__` method; but this code doesn't do this.

So I'm not talking about adding a new feature to Python. Really the question is one of language design: Why not provide it as, say, `functools.instancemethod`? If the answer is simply, "The use cases are so obscure that nobody's bothered," that's okay. But I would be happy to learn about other reasons, if there are any.

Comment: Probably because no one thought it needed one (it's the default method type). Regardless, you can make `class B` work by using: `__hash__ = lambda self: operator.attrgetter('_hash_cache')(self)`.

Comment: @martineau Using a lambda was my thought as well - `classmethod` and `staticmethod` exist because they explicitly declare non-standard behavior. At any rate, using a lambda here is roughly as pythonic as `instancemethod(operator.attrgetter('_hash_cache'))` would be, so if lambdas could cover the use case there wouldn't necessarily be an idiomatic reason to include `instancemethod`.

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy: Since it can be done without inventing a new type, there's no reason to add one. This doesn't require `lamba`, it just happens to be a succinct way to do it so that's what I put in my comment. In fact, some folks feel `lamba` _isn't_ "pythonic"...

Comment: What was the problem with just having a regular method as in your first code snippet? It seems like that's the wanted behaviour

Comment: @martineau: Mixing `lambda` with `operator.attrgetter` is silly. If we've decided to use a `lambda`, then `__hash__ = lambda self: self._hash_cache` is better all around. And it's really the same as the `__hash__` of the class `A`, as `dis.dis` will show you.

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy: But in the cases above, `instancemethod` would explicit declare non-standard behavior as well: It would convert objects that could not be used as instance methods into ones that can. I suspect that internally, CPython already has some facilities similar to what `instancemethod` would accomplish, since after all it gives function objects a `__get__`. But I don't know why they're not exposed.

Comment: Ozob: Agree that using `operator.attrgetter()` is unnecessary and besides, `__hash__ = lambda self: self._hash_cache` would be even more succinct and well as more efficient. However the fact that both they _work_, only further bolsters my claim that having an `instancemethod` type in the language is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman: There's nothing wrong with having a regular function. Initially, I wanted to define `__hash__` using `operator.attrgetter` because I thought it would make the code clearer. Having to surround it with `instancemethod` would probably nullify this for most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a satisfying answer to my question. Python does have the internal interface necessary for an `instancemethod` function, but it's not exposed by default.

```
import ctypes
import operator

instancemethod = ctypes.pythonapi.PyInstanceMethod_New
instancemethod.argtypes = (ctypes.py_object,)
instancemethod.restype = ctypes.py_object

class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self._hash_cache = hash(x)

    __hash__ = instancemethod(operator.attrgetter('_hash_cache'))

a = A(1)
print(hash(a))
```

The `instancemethod` function this creates works in essentially the same way as `classmethod` and `staticmethod`.  These three functions return new objects of types `instancemethod`, `classmethod`, and `staticmethod`, respectively.  We can see how they work by looking at `Objects/funcobject.c`.  These objects all have `__func__` members which store a callable object.  They also have a `__get__`.  For a `staticmethod` object, the `__get__` returns `__func__` unchanged.  For a `classmethod` object, `__get__` returns a bound method object, where the binding is to the class object.  And for a `staticmethod` object, `__get__` returns a bound method object, where the binding is to the object instance.  This is precisely the same behavior as `__get__` for a function object and is exactly what we want.

The only documentation on these objects seems to be in the Python C API [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/method.html#instance-method-objects).  My guess is that they're not exposed because they're so rarely needed.  I think it would be nice to have `PyInstanceMethod_New` available as `functools.instancemethod`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `instancemethod` decorator because this is the default behaviour for functions declared inside a class.

```
class A:
    ...

    # This is an instance method
    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash_cache
```

Any callable which does not have a `__get__` method can thus be wrapped into an instance method like so.

```
class A:
    def instance_method(*args):
        return any_callable(*args)
```

Thus creating an `instancemethod` decorator would just add another syntax for a feature which already exists. This would go against the saying that [there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3).

## Side note

If it is so expensive to hash your instances, you might want to avoid calling you hash function on instantiation and delay it for when the object are hashed.

One way to do that could be to set the attribute `_hash_cache` in `__hash__` instead of `__init__`. Although, let me suggest a slightly more self-contained methods which relies on caching your hash.

```
from weakref import finalize

class CachedHash:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __hash__(self, _cache={}):
        if id(self) not in _cache:
            finalize(self, _cache.pop, id(self))
            _cache[id(self)] = hash(self.x) # or some complex hash function
        return _cache[id(self)]
```

The use of [`finalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize) ensures the cache is cleared of an `id` when its instance is garbage collected.

Comment: I agree that having only one obvious way to do things is a good principle, but sometimes that obvious way depends on the context. Consider the `operator` module, for example. The functions `lambda x, y: x * y` and `operator.mul` have identical behavior. But in some contexts, one is more legible than the other. For instance, I would much rather read `cents = dollars * 100` than `cents = operator.mul(dollars, 100)`. But I'd also prefer `functools.reduce(operator.mul, ...)` to `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, ...)`. In some cases, I feel like `instancemethod` might be good style.

Comment: Also, I agree that if there's doubt that the instance will be hashed, then it's better to create `_hash_cache` on demand. My preferred way of doing this is to define a `cachedproperty` class and, in `A`, have `@cachedproperty def _hash_cache(self): return hash(self.x)`. The `cachedproperty` class is a descriptor with `def __init__(self, func): self.func = func` and `def __get__(self, instance, owner): if instance is None: return self x = self.func(instance) setattr(instance, self.func.__name__, x) return x`. This is what the project referenced in the question actually does.